# "Connection timed out" for certain websites if using Chrome/Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

**Problem**

Until yesterday, I was able to browse to all the sites I needed using Firefox. But somehow after a reboot I can no longer visit some of the websites such as https://stackoverflow.com using Firefox (this has happened before to chrome, which is why I switched to Firefox. Nowt this happened to Firefox as well).

However, if I use the UR browser, it seems to work all the times, which is why I am able to post here. Yet I would like to stick with using Firefox, so I would like to ask some help on solving this issue:

[image: certain websites not loading in firefox]

**Attempts Made**

I have attempted the following and none worked:

- clearing the cache/browsing history
- reinstalling firefox
- doing `ipconfig /flushdns` (I don't think it is a DNS problem since UR browser worked)
- turn off firewall
- switching to safe mode (disabled all extensions)

**Environment**
I am currently on:

- Windows 11
- Firefox version 96.0.1 (64-bit)